# What is the workflow for contributing to an open source git repository?

Tags: git, github, tfs, azure-devops

I have to admit I've never contributed to an open source project because I do not understand the workflow. I've looked around many times at the git documentation but found it too hard.

I have made pull requests to private repositories for my client using a front-end like Team Foundation Server (TFS) or Visual Studio Team Services (was Visual Studio Online) for git repositories. I can also easily work alone on git repositories using the git commandline because that workflow is simple. But I would like to learn the git workflow using its commandline to contribute to open source projects.

I read the following articles from the github documentation. I think I kind of know the workflow but I am not sure and I am scared to try it out on someone else's project.

1. [Fork a Repo](https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo/)
2. [Syncing a fork](https://help.github.com/articles/syncing-a-fork/)
3. [About pull requests](https://help.github.com/articles/about-pull-requests/)
4. [About collaborative development models](https://help.github.com/articles/about-collaborative-development-models/)
5. [Creating a pull request from a fork](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-pull-request-from-a-fork/)
6. [Creating a pull request](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-pull-request/)

What I really need is for someone to simplify the steps in a few, easy to understand bullet points.

From my research so far, here is what I understand.

Let us assume we want to contribute to an imaginary project named **Boo Boo**, the owner of which is named **Baabaa**. Let us assume that I, the person who wants to contribute to **Boo Boo**, have a github account at https://www.github.com/Water-Cooler-v2/

Below are the steps I know the workflow till. After these steps, I don't quite know what to do.

1. First I fork **Boo Boo** from https://www.github.com/Baabaa/Boo-Boo into my own github account. Now, I have my own **Boo Boo** fork at https://www.github.com/Water-Cooler-v2/Boo-Boo.
2. Then, I clone my own **Boo Boo** into a folder on my computer like so:

   `MrWaterCooler@WatersComputer MINGW64 /c/WaterCooler/MyFolder/
   $ git clone https://www.github.com/Water-Cooler-v2/Boo-Boo.git`

   This links my local copy of the repository in the folder *MyFolder/Boo-Boo* with the `remote` named `origin` that points to my own fork, i.e. at https://www.github.com/Water-Cooler-v2/Boo-Boo.git
3. Then, I link my local repository in *Myfolder/Boo-Boo* with **Baabaa**'s remote repository also. I do this by copying the url of **Baabaa**'s repository and typing:

   `MrWaterCooler@WatersComputer MINGW64 /c/WaterCooler/MyFolder/Boo-Boo
   $ git remote add upstream https://www.github.com/Baabaa/Boo-Boo.git`
4. Next, I verify that the new remote named `upstream` has been linked to:

   `MrWaterCooler@WatersComputer MINGW64 /c/WaterCooler/MyFolder/Boo-Boo
   $ git remote --v`
5. Next, I fetch all the branches from the remote `upstream` into my local repository in my computer by typing:

   `MrWaterCooler@WatersComputer MINGW64 /c/WaterCooler/MyFolder/Boo-Boo
   $ git fetch upstream/master`
6. Now, I checkout my local `master` branch, which would anyway be checked out by default, but I'll check it out anyway just to be sure:

   `MrWaterCooler@WatersComputer MINGW64 /c/WaterCooler/MyFolder/Boo-Boo
   $ git checkout master`
7. Then, I'll make some changes to the files in my local repository. In this case, I'll edit an existing file (not shown below because that doesn't use any git commands), and I'll add a new file named MyNewFile.txt.

   `MrWaterCooler@WatersComputer MINGW64 /c/WaterCooler/MyFolder/Boo-Boo
   $ touch MyNewFile.txt`
8. Now, I'll merge the `upstream/master` branch into my own `master` branch.

   `MrWaterCooler@WatersComputer MINGW64 /c/WaterCooler/MyFolder/Boo-Boo
   $ git merge upstream/master`

And then, now is the step I am not so clear about. Do I push? To where? My own fork (remote `origin master`) or **Baabaa**'s **Boo-Boo** (remote `upstream master`)?

Or, do I create a pull request?

Could you please validate the workflow for the first 8 steps listed above, and then complete it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just fork the repo, clone it to your local machine, optionally create a branch and do your changes. It really doesn't matter how you work locally or in your own repo. You don't have to use GitFlow. You can do Trunk-based development or whatever works for you. When you are done, you push it to your own repo. Then go to GitHub and open a PR against the original repo. That's all there is to it.

Regarding adding the original as a remote: the main reason to add the original repo as a remote is when you intend to update your fork with changes from the original repo (merging, rebasing, cherry-picking, etc). If you just intend to do a one-shot contribution to the original, like fixing some bug, it's usually not necessary to have the remote. It makes sense to add it for long term contributions though.

Comment: Thank you. I think I understand what you're saying. You're saying: make a topical branch to do your work because it's better than just doing it in the local master. That's fine. And then the last 2 steps you added are: (1) Push your local `master` to *your forked* remote `origin master`. Then, go to **BaaBaa**'s **BooBoo** repository and create a new pull request for them to pull from your fork. Is my summary right?

Comment: @WaterCoolerv2 almost. You don't have to go to the original repo to create a PR. Go to your own repo, click on `Pull Requests`, then `New Pull Request`. The drop-downs in the dialogue will have the original repo available. So you can create the PR against the original from there.

Comment: Wonderful. Thank you very much. I am trying this thing out and will mark your answer as the right one soon after I have done it once.

Comment: Just clarifying something. Then I also do not need to add the `upstream` remote, right? I can simply make changes in my own fork and create a pull request?

Comment: Oh wait! But I might (and probably will) need to link to the `upstream` remote in order to `fetch` and `merge` their work into my own repo so I have the latest of their work as well and so that I am able to merge any conflicts that my work might have created. Thanks.

Comment: You want to create the upstream branch to bring your fork up-to-date. Another good reason always working on a topic branch as it makes updating your fork easier.

Comment: @Dennis I don't agree to "it makes updating your fork easier". If updating a fork is a problem, it's usually because it's not updated often enough. Branches don't cure that problem, they make it worse. They just postpone the merge conflicts to a later time when you integrate back; and then usually with more conflicts to solve. That's contrary to the idea of Continuous Integration and Deployment. I have successfully done projects with trunk-based-development using branch-by-abstraction instead of gitflow. It takes more skill and discipline though, so I understand branches feel more convenient.

Comment: I do agree that branches make it easier for the PR receiver though because PRs are effectively frozen (unless you keep pushing to them of course). Ultimately, I think people should use the workflow they are most productive with. That's why I said "*optionally* create a branch".

Comment: @Gordon I prefer to keep the fork `origin/master` untouched so that I can fast-forward merge with the `upstream/master`. `git fetch upstream && git merge upstream/master origin/master --ff-only`. 

The great thing about `git` is that there are so many workflows you can have.

Comment: @Dennis yupp, agree.

Comment: Why you didn't use gitflow?

Answer (score 3):

Your workflow is correct.

- Always create your own branch on your fork and push that to `origin`. Creating the branch helps the maintainer when reviewing your branch.
- Once your changes are pushed, go to original repo and there should be a button at the top of the page prompting you to create the Pull Request.

Typically, the most challenging part of contributing to open source projects is finding where to start. To help with this problem, there are two sites to help find projects with nice jump issues.

http://up-for-grabs.net/#/
https://yourfirstpr.github.io/

Comment: Thanks very much. Immensely helpful.

Comment: Note, after a few PRs you will likely be given write permissions to that repository. Anyone that shows interest in the projects I maintain, I give them access.

Comment: If it is not too much of a bother, could you please make a small test repo, so I can try creating a PR for it and you can then pull? That way, I'll be able to see this in action? :-)

Comment: I just created an issue that requires a small change to a README.md file. https://github.com/dennisroche/DateTimeProvider/issues/21.

Comment: Thank you. Please give me some time to meander about the place, think some thoughts and then I will create a topical branch and a PR from that. My github is https://github.com/Sathyaish Many, many thanks. :-)

Comment: No problem. I like to encourage people to contribute. I ran a hack-a-thon last year to do that.

Comment: I think I just created a PR from a topical branch. Now, do I close the pull request? Or do you first merge and then you close the pull request? https://github.com/dennisroche/DateTimeProvider/pull/22

Comment: @WaterCoolerv2 the maintainers review the PR and add any comments on things. a good maintainer will have automatic build in place so that you will know if fails to compile. once happy, the maintainer will give a thumbs-up or :+1: on the PR and merge.

Comment: actually you helped me so much by participating with me in teaching me how to do it. But upon reading the answers, just for the sake of curation, I think Gordon's answer describes the workflow for any other reader. So, please don't mind. I am marking his answer as the right one. :-)

Comment: +1 for "Creating the branch helps the maintainer when reviewing your branch". Drives me crazy when people don't do that.